# Regarding thread communication to post task back from called child thread to main thread

Tags: multithreading

I have a requirement to post a task from child thread to main thread back. I am creating child thread from the main thread and posting tasks over there. But after receiving few callbacks from common API, I need to execute a few particular tasks on main thread only like proxy creation, etc. so in such a scenario, I have to communicate with the main thread and need to post that particular task on the main thread. I have designed LoopingThread.cpp as mentioned below and communicating with the main for posting tasks on that:

**LoopingThread.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "loopingThread.hpp"

using namespace std;

LoopingThread::LoopingThread() : thread(nullptr), scheduledCallbacks() {

}

LoopingThread::~LoopingThread() {
  if (this->thread) {
    delete this->thread;
  }
}

void LoopingThread::runCallbacks() {
  this->callbacksMutex.lock();
  if (this->scheduledCallbacks.size() > 0) {
    std::thread::id threadID = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::cout<<"inside runCallback()threadId:"<<threadID<<std::endl;
    // This is to allow for new callbacks to be scheduled from within a callback
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> currentCallbacks = std::move(this->scheduledCallbacks);
    this->scheduledCallbacks.clear();
    this->callbacksMutex.unlock();
    for (auto callback : currentCallbacks) {
      //callback();
      //this->callback();
      int id = 1;
      this->shared_func(id);
    }
  } else {
    this->callbacksMutex.unlock();
  }
}

void LoopingThread::shared_func(int id)
{
    std::thread::id run_threadID = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::cout<<"shared_func: "<<run_threadID<<std::endl;
    this->callbacksMutex.lock();
    if (id == 0)
        std::cout<<"calling from main,id: "<<id<<std::endl;
    else if (id == 1)
        std::cout<<"calling from child,id: "<<id<<std::endl;
    this->callbacksMutex.unlock();
}

void LoopingThread::run() {
  std::thread::id run_threadID = std::this_thread::get_id();
  std::cout<<"Child_run_threadID: "<<run_threadID<<std::endl;
  for (;;) {
    this->runCallbacks();
    // Run the tick
    if (!this->tick()) {
      std::cout<<"Run the tick"<<std::endl;
      break;
    }
  }

  // Run pending callbacks, this might result in an infinite loop if there are more
  // callbacks scheduled from within scheduled callbacks
  this->callbacksMutex.lock();
  while (this->scheduledCallbacks.size() > 0) {
    std::cout<<"inside scheduledCallbacks.size() > 0"<<std::endl;
    this->callbacksMutex.unlock();
    this->runCallbacks();
    this->callbacksMutex.lock();
  }
  this->callbacksMutex.unlock();
}

void LoopingThread::scheduleCallback(std::function<void()> callback) {
  std::cout<<"inside schedulecallback"<<std::endl;
  this->callbacksMutex.lock();
  this->scheduledCallbacks.push_back(callback);
  this->callbacksMutex.unlock();
}

void LoopingThread::start() {
  if (!this->thread) {
    this->thread = new std::thread(&LoopingThread::run, this);
    //std::thread::id threadID = std::this_thread::get_id();
    //std::cout<<"creating thread: "<<threadID<<std::endl;
  }
}

void LoopingThread::join() {
  if (this->thread && this->thread->joinable()) {
    this->thread->join();
    std::cout<<"joining thread"<<std::endl;
  }
}

**main.cpp:**

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>

#include "loopingThread.hpp"

using namespace std;

std::mutex stdoutMutex;

// Example usage of LoopingThread with a classic MainThread:
class MainThread : public LoopingThread {
private:
  MainThread();

public:
  virtual ~MainThread();

  static MainThread& getInstance();
  virtual bool tick();
};

MainThread::MainThread() {}
MainThread::~MainThread() {}

MainThread& MainThread::getInstance() {
  // Provide a global instance
  static MainThread instance;
  return instance;
}

bool MainThread::tick() {
    //  std::cout<<"main thread:"<<threadID<<std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  stdoutMutex.lock();
  std::cout << "tick" << std::endl;
  stdoutMutex.unlock();

  // Return false to stop this thread
  return true;
}

void doLongAsyncTask() {
  std::thread longTask([] () {

    stdoutMutex.lock();
    std::cout << "Beginning long task..." <<std::endl;
    stdoutMutex.unlock();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    stdoutMutex.lock();
    std::cout << "Long task finished!" << std::endl;
    stdoutMutex.unlock();

    MainThread::getInstance().scheduleCallback([] () {
      stdoutMutex.lock();
      std::cout << "This is called within the main thread!" << std::endl <<
                   "No need to worry about thread safety or " <<
                   "race conditions here" << std::endl;
      stdoutMutex.unlock();
    });
  });
  longTask.detach();
}

int main() {
  doLongAsyncTask();
  MainThread::getInstance().start();

  MainThread::getInstance().join();

  MainThread::getInstance().run();

}
```

Now suppose child thread receives any task of creating proxy then It needs to post that task back to the main thread. How to achieve this scenario?